# Change created user success message

Tags: customer, vat

When people sign up on my webshop they are automatically assigned to a customer group.
When they first create a user they get the following success message on the dashboard;

```
Thank you for registering with //webshop name//.
If you are a registered VAT customer, please click here to enter you billing address for proper VAT calculation.
```

The problem is that I do not use VAT in my shop. 
I've been looking through the local files, but I can't find it anywhere. How do I change or delete this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

McKeene,you have enable Vat setting to system.for checking please goto `admin>system>configuration>Customer>Create New Account>Enable Automatic Assignment` to Customer Group make it know

As you enable Automatic customer group assign then magento feature to  added customer  to registered VAT customer which is need VAT Calculation

Comment: Ah thank you. I guess I misunderstood the settings.
To make it work i changed Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group to no, like you said and then changed Default Group to the Customer Group I wanted.